# React HTMLAudioElement won't pause

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, next.js

I have a component in React that takes a URL and shows a button that lets the user stop/pause an audio file.  This component is used multiple times on the page.

The button starts the audio just fine, however it `audio.pause()` does not stop the stream.

I am using Next.js, however I am importing the component like so:

```
const HistoryRow = dynamic(() => import('../components/HistoryRow'), { ssr: false });
```

Anyone know why this doesn't stop the stream? I can confirm it's entering the if statement just fine.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import m from 'moment';
import path from 'path';

function HistoryRow({ data }) {
  const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);
  const audio = new Audio(`${window.location.origin}/audio-responses/${data.timestamp}.wav`);

  audio.onended = function () {
    setPlaying(false);
  };

  audio.onpause = function () {
    setPlaying(false);
  };

  audio.onplay = function () {
    setPlaying(true);
  };

  audio.onerror = function () {
    setPlaying(false);
  };

  function execute() {
    if (playing) {
      audio.pause();
    } else {
      audio.play();
    }
  }

  const stopSvg = (
    <svg> /** svg data ** / </svg>
  );

  const playSvg = (
    <svg> /** svg data ** / </svg>
  );

  return (
      <div className="text-base flex leading-5 font-medium text-blue-600 truncate" onClick={() => execute()}>
        {data.type === 'command' ? (playing ? stopSvg : playSvg) : null}
      </div>  
  );
}

export default HistoryRow;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you state changes, the whole component is rerendered. This means that every variable in the component is rewritten. So you create an `Audio` instance, then start playing, the component rerenders and a new `Audio` instance is created en therefor you've lost the binding to the previous instance.

You can use the [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook to create a reference to the `Audio` instance that persists over the entire lifespan of the component. So it will never change unless you explicitly tell it to. You can access the instance with the `current` property on the returned `useRef` value.

Since React is *state driven* I would suggest using the [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) hook to listen for changes in the `playing` state and either start or stop playing based on the value of the `playing` state, that's the other way around as you have it currently.

```
function HistoryRow({ data }) {
  const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);
  const [hasError, setHasError] = useState(false);
  const audio = useRef(new Audio(`${window.location.origin}/audio-responses/${data.timestamp}.wav`));

  audio.current.onended = function () {
    setPlaying(false);
  };

  audio.current.onplay = function () {
    setHasError(false);
  };

  const handleClick = () => {
    setPlaying(playing => !playing);
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (playing) {
      audio.current.play().then(() => {
        // Audio is playing.
      }).catch(error => {
        setHasError(true);
      });
    } else if (!hasError) {
      audio.current.pause();
    }
  }, [playing, hasError]);

  const stopSvg = (
    <svg> /* svg data */ </svg>
  );

  const playSvg = (
    <svg> /* svg data */ </svg>
  );

  return (
      <div 
        className="text-base flex leading-5 font-medium text-blue-600 truncate" 
        onClick={handleClick}>
        {data.type === 'command' ? (playing ? stopSvg : playSvg) : null}
      </div>  
  );
}
```

Comment: Ahhh of course!  Didn't even cross my mind.  That works perfect, thanks!

Comment: You saved me from a lot hassles.